# why cout is not printing this string?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring

So, I'm new to C++ and I can't figure why this is happening. I have a string with all the alphabets and I copied 10 characters from it into a new string `s2`, character by character using a for loop as follows and when I execute it the `cout` function is printing a blank line.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string s2;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        s2[i] = s[i];
    }
    cout << s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I print this string `s2` character by character I got the correct output

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string s2;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        s2[i] = s[i];
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << s2[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);` - Why all this nonsense?

Comment: @JesperJuhl • (deadpan) So the program is performant.  Otherwise it will be too slow. (/deadpan)

Comment: You did not `#include <string>`, but you added all sorts of `sync_with_stdio` stuff for no reason..

Comment: You tagged the question with c-strings but there aren't any c-strings in your code.

Comment: @Eljay Well, the program does hardly anything other than output, so the synccing overhead might actually be significant enough to be measurable.

Comment: @Eljay If those statements make a difference, then the program has other issues. Those statements *can* make sense if you are trying to shave off every last ms, but for most (real) applications they won't matter one iota.

Comment: @JesperJuhl forgot to mention I encountered this when I was solving a problem on codeforces and `ios::sync_with_stdio` will help in fast I/O

Comment: @eerorika Maybe if it was outputting megabytes of data, but a few characters?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it didn't work when I include `<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm pretty sure Eljay was being just a little bit sarcastic.

Comment: *it didn't work when I include <bits/stdc++.h>* -- That's a relief -- now you're forced to actually include the correct headers.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @jaychandra "it didn't work when I include <bits/stdc++.h>" - You should *never* do that. Why would you ever want to include a non-standard and non-portable header in the first place? That header is internal to the implementation, you are not supposed to include it. And if you do include it you've just made sure your code won't compile with any other compiler and you've also just dragged in *all* of the standard library, which hurts your compile times and increases the risk of name collisions. *Why* would you *ever* do that?

Comment: Thank you @Shawn for that article, I'll try to use it less from now

Comment: It's somehow funny to use `ios::sync_with_stdio` to optimize performance but to copy a string without preallocating memory.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JesperJuhl I will stop using `<bits/stdc++.h>` from now :)

Comment: @jaychandra Currious; what caused you to include it in the first place?

Comment: I've been practicing competitive programming and found that most people use `<bits/stdc++.h>` so I started using it.

Comment: That's called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming. Most people in competitive are bad programmers. You shouldn't learn from them.

Comment: ah sure thing, I'll keep that in mind @ThomasSablik

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both your code have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). `string s2;` just initializes `s2` as an empty `std::string` which contains no elements. Trying to access element as `s2[i]` leads to UB, means anything is possible. (Even it appears to give the correct output in your 2nd code snippet.)

You can use `push_back` to append element as

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    s2.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

Or

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    s2 += s[i];
}
```

Or you can make `s2` containing 10 elements in advance.

```
string s2(10, '\0'); // or... string s2; s2.resize(10);
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    s2[i] = s[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An empty string `s2` is created. `s2[i] = s[i];` won't resize the string but it causes undefined behavior. One way to solve the problem is to append each character. This will change the size and can involve multiple memory allocations.

Another way is to create a string with correct size or reserve memory with:

1. Create "empty" string with size 10:

   ```
    string s2(10, '\0');
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        s2[i] = s[i];
    }
   ```
2. Reserve memory

   ```
    string s2;
    s2.reserve(10);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        s2 += s[i];
    }
   ```
3. Initialize the string with a substring

   ```
    string s2 = s.substr(0, 10);
   ```

   or

   ```
    string s2(s.begin(), s.begin() + 10);
   ```

   or

   ```
    string s2(s, 0, 10);
   ```

Comment: One more possible solution that maybe more clear for beginners `string s2(s, 0, 10);`.

Comment: @S.M. Great. Didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

One might be confused, because

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cout << s2[i];
}
```

delivers the correct output. The `std::string` is a class with functions and overloaded operators.
The `[]-operator` of the `std::string` shows a similar behaviour as a `char-array`.
The "array-elements" are defined with this code snipped:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        s2[i] = s[i];
    }
```

If the code of the question is executed several times, the undefined behaviour of this snipped can be seen.

If you try to use a string iterator you will see, that the string `s2` is still an empty string.

```
string::iterator si;
    for (si=s2.begin(); si!=s2.end(); si++)
    {
        cout << *si ;
    }
```